# How to get a .jpg image from external website and store it (Storing it seperate from CURL)

Tags: php, curl

I am currently attempting to make a function in my class which gets data from an external server.
I am able to get the data with CURL, but I do not want to use CURL to directly store it in a file. 
This is semi difficult to explain so I will show you.

This is my function for getting the image:

```
function getCharacterPortrait($CharID, $size){

    $url = "http://image.eveonline.com/character/{$CharID}_{$size}.jpg";
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,
    ));
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;

}
```

So, what I want to do from here, is take the `$data` which is the raw image I presume, and store it in a `.jpg` in a specified file.
I have found a similar explanation for this using CURL, but CURL was used to directly store it. I would like the script that is calling the function to get the image to store the file.

Sorry if I am being a bit confusing, but I think you get the premise of what I am saying. If more explaining is needed please do say so.

Comment: Nope. I am still not clear. I think you found an example with CURL. There file was directly stored and you were not able to place the file in desired location.

Comment: What about using `file_get_contents()` instead of CURL ?

Comment: use `file_get_contents()` and match image tag with the returned content using `preg_match_all()`.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
$a = implode('',@file('http://url/file.jpg'));
$h = fopen('/path/to/disk/file.jpg','wb');
fwrite($h,$a);
fclose($h);
```

Comment: This works, Thanks! Just wondering but what is the `wb` mean, I know`w` means write but I cannot find anything about b

Answer (score 0):

Just write all the data cURL gave you to a file with [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/file_put_contents) for example?

```
[your curl code...]
file_put_contents('localcopy.jpg', $data);
```

---

**Edit:**

Apparently there is also a cURL option to download to a file like:

```
$fp = fopen($path, 'w');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
```

*Found at http://www.phpriot.com/articles/download-with-curl-and-php*

Answer (score 0):

Use it

```
$url = "http://image.eveonline.com/character/{$CharID}_{$size}.jpg";
$local_path = "myfolder/{$CharID}_{$size}.jpg";
$file = file_get_contents($url);
file_put_contents($file, $local_path);
```